# Reading a data as empty when before it's read in the subset of a dataframe

Tags: r, graph, subset

Good morning,

I have some troubles to understand the logic of dataframe in R programming

I have a list of cities and relative distances in a CSV file with this structure

**DEPARTURE;DESTINATION;DISTANCE;**

where *DEPARTURE* and *DESTINATION* have the name of the cities and *DISTANCE* the distance between these.

Example of the datas

```
ANCONA;ASCOLIPICENO;83.0;
ANCONA;CAMPBASSO;257.0;  
ANCONA;CESENA;154.0;
ANCONA;FORLI;177.0;      
ANCONA;GIULIANOVA;106.0; 
ANCONA;SENIGALLIA;35.0;
```

my goal is to have a list of tuples

**DEPARTURE;DESTINATION;DISTANCE;**

where:
 - the *DISTANCE* between *DEPARTURE* 
 - *DESTINATION* is the smallest between *DEPARTURE* and the other cities.
 - Every city can appear as *DEPARTURE* once and as *DESTINATION* once.

My idea is
for every city

1. I flag as ELABORATED == TRUE every row that has this city as
   DEPARTURE
2. I calculate the smallest DISTANCE linked to this DEPARTURE
3. I read the DESTINATION far from this DEPARTURE with this
   calculcated *DISTANCE*
4. I save the data in one list

this is the code

```
#clean console
cat(c("\014"))
#trip in italian coast in Adriatic sea
fileToRead = "D:/workspaceR/prove/principiante/resources/viaggi/adriatico/adriatico.csv"
cities = read.table(header = TRUE, sep = ';', file = fileToRead)

#add ID column to dataframe, can be useful
cities$ID <- seq.int(nrow(cities))

#control the data
dim(cities)
head(cities)
#it's OK

#remove useless data
#data cleaned
#list of city, one occourrence for city
single_departure <- sort(unique(cities$DEPARTURE))

#add column ELABORATED = FALSE if not read, TRUE if it's read in elaboration
cities$ELABORATED = FALSE

#add column TO_VISIT = FALSE if it's a possibile destination, TRUE if it's a real destination
cities$TO_VISIT = FALSE

# declare final list
result <- c(nrow(single_departure)) 

#variable debug, using 1 city of test
flag <- TRUE #debug, using 1 city of test

#elaboration flow
for (single in single_departure) {

  #debug, using 1 city of test
  if (flag) {

    actual_departure = (cities$DEPARTURE == single) & (!(cities$ELABORATED))
    next_possible_cities = !(actual_departure)
    #print(actual_departure) # dataframe of LOGICAL data
    #print(single) # Correct reading of the actual departure city 

    smallest_distance = min(cities[actual_departure,]$DISTANCE) #return 35, , it's OK
    trip <- paste(single,"->",smallest_distance); #2 contains ASCOLIPICENO -> 35, it's OK
    actual_destination = cities[ next_possible_cities & cities$DISTANCE == smallest_distance, ]$DESTINATION
    print((actual_destination))# why it's emtpy?? Theorically it has to be SENIGALLIA

    ###to run after fixing bug about destination
    #  trip <-paste(single, "->", actual_destination, "=", smallest_distance)
    #result[single] <- trip
    #cities[cities$DEPARTURE == single | cities$actual_destination == single,]$ELABORATED = TRUE
    #  cities[ actual_departure & cities$DISTANZA == smallest_distance & cities$actual_destination == actual_destination,]$TO_VISIT= TRUE

    flag <- FALSE#debug 1 city
  }#debug 1 city
}
```

Maybe I think yet as SQL-centric logic, but I don't understand why the subsetting dosn't find the city destination (or the row) at this point but 
I can read the city destination (or the row) when I calculate the smallest distance.

Can you give me some idea how to bypass the problem and reading correctly the destination, please?

thank you

Comment: In defining `actual_destination` inside the loop, I guess you want `actual_departure` instead of `next_possible_cities`.

Comment: @nicola, Hi, really I don't: I want populate *actual_destination* as  a subset f the cities that are next_possible_cites (cities that are not yet elaborated) and with smallest distance form current city. Thank you

Comment: Before saying "really I don't" did you try my suggestion? That line doesn't make sense if you think about it. You search which is the minimum distance from city `single` and then you search if other cities (?) has the same minimum distance. In that line at the first iteration you are saying: select any row where departure is different from `ANCONA` and distance is 35. See that it doesn't make sense?

Comment: @nicola Sorry, only now I get your point. I was focalized in choising the destination between the not elaborated cities, but you're right, I put the condition of not elaborated cities in departure. If you want, you can copy your first comment as response and I will select it as best response. Thank you again